# I am facing issue with accessing imap.gmail.com in azure pipeline

Tags: gmail-imap, multi-factor-authentication, azure-devops-pipelines

In selenium for my automation script I have to retrieve MFA code from my external test user(*something@gmail.com*). I am using talking to the IMAP gmail incoming server with this code
`using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient(GmailHostName, 993, email, ClientEmailPassword, AuthMethod.Login, true))`
When I run this test locally it works successfully getting the MFA code from gmail account. But in **Azure Devops Pipeline** the same test fails to retrieve the code. This is the error from Azure:
`System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 108.177.122.109:993`

````
   at S22.Imap.ImapClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port, Boolean ssl, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validate)```
   at S22.Imap.ImapClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port, String username, String password, AuthMethod method, Boolean ssl, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validate)

Has anyone faced an issue like this? Any and all help will be highly appreciated.
````

Comment: Yes, experiencing issues with this too. Haven't found a solution yet, or anything documenting this.